# Eclipse Tahu: Configure Use of TLS in Java

Tags: java, ssl, mqtt, mqtt-sparkplug

My organization is building an application to support MQTT Sparkplug B in Java (Spring Boot/Eclipse Tahu 1.0.4). It seems that the majority of the wrappers require a collection of `MqttServerDefinition` objects, which all require basic auth credentials. Is there an example somewhere of using TLS?

Best I can tell, the only other option is extending the `TahuClient` class to access the `MqttConnectOptions` and set a custom `SocketFactory` (this is straightforward for the Host, but very hacky for the Client).